# How can I display image in JSP?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, jstl, el

I am trying to display user avatar stored in DB on User Personal page (JSP) here is what I do

1- I have a servlet processing login request and produce User Bean object. (User Avatar as     byte array ,it may appear multiple times on different pages and locations that's why I prefer session attribute rather than read them each time from DB)

2- The User bean is stored in session as attribute.

3- I want to have another JSP or Servlet to display this byte array avatar as image anytime.

4- I also whish this Servlet could be reusable for other icon images, that's why I think it can not rely on session attributes to pass byte array? (I am not quite sure about this)

so Is there any design to achieve what I want ? or should I simply use session attributes to pass data around?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> *How can I display image in JSP?*

Using the HTML `<img>` element.

---

> *Is there any design to achieve what I want?*

You could just create a standalone servlet for that. It's only 2 or 3 lines of code in `doGet()` method. True, this servlet would not really be reuseable for streaming images straight from the DB, but you could just create another one. That isn't a major problem IMHO.

---

> *or should I simply use session attributes to pass data around?*

Only if it really represents sessionwide data and you've based on performance measurements confirmed that keeping the user's avatar in session is faster than streaming it from the DB everytime. Keep in mind that any data in the session scope accumulates server's memory, so make sure that those images doesn't exceed a certain file size.

Answer (score 0):

If the avatar isn't some very secret thing, I would create a servlet that takes a userid parameter and get the image data from the DB. Embedding would look like:

> `<img src="/avatarservlet?userid=XXX"/>`

That will solve almost everything, except the performance problem. Instead of passing the image data around in the session (baaaaaad idea), you have two options:

1. Add expires/cache headers in your servlet, so browsers will do the caching.
2. Since your servlet will be stateless, it's an ideal candidate for method caching. see http://ehcache.org/documentation/recipes/spring-annotations